# Line break widgets at line ending

Tags: tkinter

I want to draw multiple widgets in a row. The problem is, I don't want to scroll horizontally . THe lines of widgets should wrap at the end of the line (like inline elements in HTML/CSS would do).

But how can this be achieved? How to wrap widgets at line ending?

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Button, Frame

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
for _ in range(10):
    button = Button(frame)
    button.pack(side='left')
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to put the widgets in a `Text` widget with wrapping turned on.

It might look something like this:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text
from tkinter.ttk import Button

root = Tk()
container = Text(root, wrap="char")
container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for _ in range(10):
    button = Button(container, text=f"Button #{_}")
    container.window_create("end", window=button)
container.configure(state="disabled")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot - narrow]
[image: screenshot - wide]

Comment: Interresting. Never thought about using a Text widget. Will try to make this look and feel like a frame. If this works, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: OK, in addition to this solution: state=disable, borderwidth=0, cursor=arrow and using the background of a frame as background: `s = Style()`, `bg = s.lookup('TFrame', 'background')`, `text.configure(background=bg)`.

Comment: For some reason line breaks only work if widget is not disabled.

Comment: One has to set state to normal, edit the Text widget, and change state back to disabled.

Comment: @Michael every other possible solution would requires you to write "some" code. It seems a convenient solution and works flawless for me when using `container.configure(state="disabled", bg=container.master.cget('bg'))` and `container = Text(root, wrap="char", cursor='')` instead. It might be possible that `state="readonly"` works for your case better.

Comment: @Michael: it works for me enabled or disabled. It has to be enabled to insert the buttons, but after that they wrap just fine even in the disabled state.

Comment: Yes, but to add a forced line break or delete the widgets I have to enable it. It's not part of my question but wnated to add those notes here.

Comment: @Michael: yes, you have to re-enable the widget to make changes.

Comment: Another finding: If the mouse is over a sub-widget, it's impossible to scroll. You can only scroll if the mouse in empty area of the Text widget.

Comment: @Michael: good point, though that can be fixed.